# filter internal traffic using google tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to filter the internal traffic using google tag manager.

I did all the steps mentioned in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nT2uFCNv_4&feature=youtu.be

One thing i noticed is that in my case google tag assistant showing tow google analytics with same id. one have custom metric and other don't have.

Any help is highly appreciated.

! http://34.212.161.182/ga.png

Comment: Just put your GTM container into "Preview" mode and find out if two GA tags are triggering at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But i just noted that google tag assistant showing 3 page view count for the same page. out of three once has custom metrics and two does not have. Does it help you to answer?